# Setting a page variable in a function

Tags: drupal-6

I'd like to set a page variable myblock = false inside my menu callback function. So that this block is not shown when the menu entry is clicked.
I want to do something like this:

```
function mymenu_cbfunction() {
    ... // $myblock=false ??
}
```

to deactive the block in page.tpl.php :

```
<?php if ($myblock):?><div>php print $myblock; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to exclude showing this block on certain pages, just edit the block at admin/build/block to exclude it on certain pages.  The configuration form looks like:

[image: Block Config]

If you want to immediately hide the block without navigating to a new page, that would be a good use for JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. No way to do it programmatically? All of my pages are created programmatically (with modules) for this site.

Comment: Sure, check out [`hook_block()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_block/6) Specifically the 'visibility' and 'pages' keys

Comment: All right. I was able to do what i wanted in hook_block. Thx for the help!